# .htaccess fails to rewrite when url contains HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've been sitting with this a long time now and can't get my head around it.

Essentially, the functionality I'm looking for in the end would be similar to the following:

`http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com` - **currently working**

and for

`http://*.example.com` and `https://*.example.com` to redirect to `https://example.com/*` - **Not working. Currently, all subdomains get redirected to the main-domain, without their respective folder path. Also, when going to `https://test.example.com`, it doesn't redirect at all.**

Here's the `example.com.conf` from `sites-enabled`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
#       Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # Redirect all traffic to HTTPS
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
        </IfModule>


    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # Remove www
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
        </IfModule>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/civrpssl/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/civrpssl/example.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/civrpssl/ca-example.com.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And finally, here's the `.htaccess` from `example.com/public_html/`:

```
removed, see edit #2.
```

I'm hoping it's a rather obvious issue that I've failed to see. Otherwise, please could someone enlighten me where I should start looking for the issue? I'm assuming that the HTTPS redirect interferes with the subdomain redirect in the .htaccess file but don't know how I could put it any differently.

**EDIT #1:** I just noticed that `www.example.com` throws error "URL not found" rather than re-directing to `https://example.com`. How comes it isn't caught by the first rewrite in `.htaccess`?

**EDIT #2:**

- Moved rewriting from `.htaccess` to `example.com.conf` (code updated in post).
- Added VHost for port 80, essentially just redirecting all traffic to HTTPS. I found that Redirect worked, however it wouldn't include and subdomains in the redirect, so `http://test.example.com` would only lead to `https://example.com`.
- Ran `a2enmod rewrite`, since apparently it wasn't enabled.

Comment: What about the vHost for port 80? The vHost you've posted only excepts requests to `example.com` - no subdomains (including `www`) are accepted. However, if this is the very first vHost defined in your config then it may still be catching these requests. Otherwise, your `.htaccess` directives look "OK", except that if you access to the server config then you should ideally be redirecting HTTP and subdomains in your server config instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've updated the post. Please, if you have the time, give it another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ServerName example.com
> ServerAlias www.example.com
> ```

Neither of the `<VirtualHost>` containers accept requests for any subdomains, except for `www`. The vHost may still catch additional subdomains (in fact, *any* hostname) if it is the first defined vHost in the server config. To catch "any" subdomain, you would need another "wildcard" `ServerAlias` of the form:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

Remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrappers - they are not required. They will only *mask* the error if mod_rewrite is not available. The `<IfModule>` wrapper should only be used if these directives are entirely *optional* and the config is to be ported to other systems where mod_rewrite is not available.

**UPDATE:** You were also missing the `RewriteEngine On` directive in the vHost. Unless the rewrite engine was already enabled elsewhere in the server config (unlikely) then these mod_rewrite directives would simply be skipped altogether.

In HTTP vHost (port 80)...

> ```
>        # Redirect all traffic to HTTPS
>        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
>        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
> ```

There's no point checking `HTTPS` in the vHost for port 80 as it will always be `off`. If you want to redirect directly from the subdomain to the subdirectory, you would need to change the above to read:

```
        # Redirect HTTP subdomains to HTTPS subdirectory (excluding www)
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

        # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, if you have any intention to implement HSTS in the future then you will need to redirect to HTTPS on the same host first and issue a second redirect to the subdirectory in the vHost for port 443 only. (Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS using the `Redirect` directive - currently commented out - although this would require a separate (minimal) vHost for each subdomain, which may not be desirable.)

`^/(.*)` - Note the addition of a slash prefix outside of the capturing subpattern in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In a *virtualhost* context, the full URL-path is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The trailing `$` is not required since regex is greedy by default.

Note also the regex `([^.]+)` (instead of `(.*)`) that specifically matches a subdomain only (no dots).

In your vHost for HTTPS (port 443) you have:

> ```
>        # Remove www
>        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
>        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
> ```

You are redirecting back to HTTP (although this seems to be a bug you have introduced after your edit?).

No need to capture the `RewriteRule` *pattern* if you are using the `REQUEST_URI` variable.

Then the same edit applies to the subdomain to subdirectory redirect as mentioned above.

### Summary

Bringing the above points together we have something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    #Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Redirect HTTP subdomains to HTTPS subdirectory (excluding www)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (www and domain apex)
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        # Set "AllowOverride None" to disable .htaccess altogether
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]

    # Redirect other subdomains to subdirectory
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/civrpssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/civrpssl/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/civrpssl/ca-example.com.crt

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

You should first test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

And clear your browser cache before testing (any erroneous 301s will have been cached by the browser).

Comment: Cheers mate! This works like a charm. I also noticed that both the original post and answer lacked `RewriteEngine on`, so I added that as well.

Comment: Follow-up question on the `Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS using the Redirect directive - currently commented out.`. I tried this but was assuming that the subdomain was lost in this kind of redirect? Would it be possible to remove Rewrite entirely from the vhost for port 80 and handle it all on 443 by simply uncommenting the Redirect line?

Comment: "I also noticed that both the original post and answer lacked `RewriteEngine on`, so I added that as well." - Oops, yes, you'll need that! (Unless it is already enabled elsewhere in the server config - unlikely.) - I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: "Would it be possible to remove Rewrite entirely from the vhost for port 80 and handle it all on 443 by simply uncommenting the Redirect line?" - Well, not quite so simple. You would need to create a minimal vHost for each subdomain which would contain the `Redirect` - so this may not be desirable. Sticking with mod_rewrite, particularly if you have many of these subdomains, would probably be preferable.